# Algorithm to find the power of 2

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have found a small algorithm to determine if a number is power of 2, but not an explanation for how it works, what really happens?

```js
var potence = n =>  n && !(n & (n - 1));


for(var i = 2; i <= 16; ++i) {
   if(potence(i)) console.log(i + " is potence of 2");
}
```

Comment: Think about the binary representation of a power of two.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new here, I recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips.

Answer (score 1):

I'll explain how it works for non-negative `n`. The first condition in `n && !(n & (n - 1))` simply checks that `n` is not zero. If `n` is not zero, then it has some least significant `1`-bit at some position `p`. Now, if you subtract `1` from `n`, all bits before position `p` will change to `1`, and the bit at `p` will flip to `0`.

Something like this:

```
n:       1010100010100111110010101000000
n-1:     1010100010100111110010100111111
                                 ^ position p
```

Now, if you `&` these two bit-patterns, all the stuff after the position `p` remains unchanged, and everything before (and including `p`) is zeroed out:

```
after &: 1010100010100111110010100000000
                                 ^ position p
```

If the result after taking `&` happens to be zero, then it means that there was nothing after position `p`, thus the number must have been 
`2^p`, which looked like this:

```
n:       0000000000000000000000001000000
n - 1:   0000000000000000000000000111111
n&(n-1): 0000000000000000000000000000000
                                 ^ position p
```

thus `n` is a power of `2`. If the result of `&` is not zero (as in the first example), then it means that there was some junk in the more significant bits after the `p`-th position, and therefore `n` is not a power of `2`.

I'm too lazy to play this through for the 2-complement representation of negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If one number is potence of 2, then must be 10...0 in binary representation. Minus by 1, then then leading `1` should be `0`, so that `n & (n-1)` to be 0. Otherwise, it is not the potence of 2.

Answer (score 0):

Kinka's answer is essentially correct, but perhaps needs a bit more detail on the "otherwise" case. If the number isn't a power of two, then it must have the form n=(2^a + 2^(b) + y), where a>b and y <2^b. Subtracting 1 from that  must be strictly greater than 2^a, so (n & (n-1)) is at least 2^a, and therefore non-zero.