# Check if a float can be converted to integer without loss

Tags: rust, idioms

I wanted to check whether an integer was a power of 2. My standard approach would have been to see if `log₂(x)` was an integer value, however I found no elegant way to do this. My approaches were the following:

```
let x = 65;

let y = (x as f64).log(2.0);

// Compute the difference between y and the result of
// of truncating y by casting to int and back
let difference = y - (y as i64 as f64);

// This looks nice but matches on float values will be phased out
match difference {
    0.0 => println!("{} is a power of 2", x),
    _ => println!("{} is NO power of 2", x),
}

// This seems kind of clunky
if difference == 0.0 {
    println!("{} is a power of 2", x);
} else {
    println!("{} is NO power of 2", x);
}
```

**Is there a builtin option in Rust to check if a float can be converted to an integer without truncation?**

Something that behaves like:

```
42.0f64.is_int() // True/ Ok()
42.23f64.is_int() // False/ Err()
```

In other words, a method/ macro/ etc. that allows me to check if I will lose information (decimals) by casting to int.

---

*I already found that checking whether an integer is a power of 2 can be done efficiently with `x.count_ones() == 1`.*

Comment: There was a post about it just yesterday. Test that `x > 0` and that `x & (x - 1) == 0`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48477020/algorithm-to-find-the-power-of-2/48477286#48477286

Comment: keep in mind that `x as u32` could already be causing loss of precision

Comment: Also: https://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html

Comment: The integer might be a power of two, but that does not imply that the original float was. Checking whether a float `x` can be losslessly converted to an int `n` involves _fraction_ `x.fract() == 0_f32` / `x == (float) n` and _spacing/overflow_ of floats: `(x + 1) != x` and `x < Integer.MAX_VALUE`. _(Sorry for the javaisms)_

Comment: If x is unsigned, `x > 0 && (x & (x-1)) == 0` is true iff x is a power of 2.

Comment: Can you please specify whether you want to know if: `Check if a float can be converted to integer without loss` or `I wanted to check whether an integer was a power of 2. `

Comment: My question is/ was: `Check if a float can be converted to integer without loss`. The power of two stuff was only my problem motivation.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use [fract](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f64.html#method.fract) to check if there is a non-zero fractional part:

```
42.0f64.fract() == 0.0;
42.23f64.fract() != 0.0;
```

Note that this only works if you already know that the number is in range. If you need an extra check to test that the floating-point number is between 0 and `u32::MAX` (or between `i32::MIN` and `i32::MAX`), then you might as well do the conversion and check that it didn't lose precision:

```
x == (x as u32) as f64
```

Comment: this covers fractions... what about f64 numbers larger than u32::MAX ?

Comment: `fract()` is actually implemented as `self - self.trunc()`, it might be better to use `v.trunc() == v` for the check instead.

Comment: @diginoise you're right, this only works for numbers that are known to be in range.

Comment: @Jmb: *Right*, I was thinking about fractions (such as 0.3) which is completely off!

Comment: `x == (x as u32) as f64` is how I've always seen this construct.

Comment: The check is indeed only half of the answer. It might be worth mentioning why `u32` is used for `f64`. A 32 bit float has 23 bits of fractional data (52 for 64-bit doubles), meaning it can only faithfully represent a whole number between [0,2^23) (also negative). For any values above that, out of bounds arithmetic or casting will floor the value. If this happens, it will not be "without loss". See: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=6ccbd5d51c8f2ae11f3b3569ecd0ff55&version=stable

Comment: @udoprog the question is: "How to check if a given **`f64`** number can be converted to an integer without loss?" Given that the input is already an `f64`, any precision-loss due to rounding will have happened **before** the conversion to integer. So the conversion itself is lossless so long as the input is in range and has 0 fractional part.

Comment: @Shepmaster Doesn't that invoke UB if x is outside the range of u32? Or has that issue finally been fixed? (Though if the float is the result of a logarithm of a value >= 1 it will always be in range, so it doesn't affect the OP's application)

Comment: @CodesInChaos I just said that that's how I've always seen it, not that it's the *right way* ;-). The [issue does seem to be open still](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/10184).

Comment: @CodesInChaos Note that it doesn't cause undefined _behaviour_ (which could include any side-effect up to the total destruction of the universe) but simply undefined _result_, meaning that the result will be some integer value and you simply don't know what that value will be. However if `x` doesn't fit in an `u32` there is no way that this value will be equal to `x` once converted back to `f64`, so the test is guaranteed to work even in that case.

Comment: @Jmb My understanding is an undefined value isn't merely an unspecified by valid value. So using it is UB.Which is why floating point to integer conversion is unsound at the moment.

Comment: @Shepmaster looks like the issue has been closed: out of range conversion are now [defined as saturating](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/71269).

Comment: @udoprog why would `v.trunc() == v` be better?

Comment: You can compare the code for both apporaches here: https://godbolt.org/z/qz3s75Mrq trunc() makes an actual function call